# Order parameters using Alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

We are needing to control the parameter order in an Alamofire request.  The parameters are supplied to Alamofire as a dictionary, and as such are not ordered.

Have also tried using an adapter, but by that time the body is encoded data, not thinking I can change that.

We need to order because of oauth, our server is using the params as part of the key and expecting a specific order.

Just in case, here is our code:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["id": "userID","service": "token"]

Alamofire.request("https://ourhost.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseString { response in
        print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
    }
    .responseJSON { response in

    print(response.result)
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print(response.result.value)
        break;
    default:
        print(response.result.error!)
        break
    }
}
```

Would welcome a way to order these items.

Comment: If you need to keep the order of the elements you need to use an array. There is no way to order the dictionary based on the order that the keys were added

Comment: Agree, but, how do you pass that array into alamofire for the param list, it wants a dict.

Comment: I cannot find any methods taking an Array as parameters. You may need to create `URLRequest` by yourself.

Comment: If you need to send a dictionary, you can send an extra key with the date the key was added and sort it base on that value.

Comment: Do you have a example on the URLRequest creation outside of the .response section?

Comment: Leo, do you have a example of this?

Comment: @RobBonner, I have never seen such code example with Alamofire, using `URLSession` directly would be a possible alternative.

Comment: did you try with any object mapper like https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper.